# Is there any way of developing asp.net application using chrome remote desktop api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome-devtools, remote-desktop

Can anybody help? 
I want to develop a web application for showing my previous remote desktop connection which made by chrome remote desktop plugin.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The "plugin" is, like it says, a piece of software running inside the browser, but fully on the client machine. It has nothing to do with Web Application development. You cannot serve "Remote Desktop" with ASP.NET.

Comment: Is there any way to make remote connection over browser ?

Comment: Not with http/web technology, no.